# How to retrive data from SQL from specific row to last record

Tags: php, sql

I want to get data from database from specific row to last row.
How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Additionally, you've tagged php, but this appears to be only a sql question.

Comment: You can find an answer for this by simply looking on google/stackoverflow for about a minute.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can set `limit` and `offset` with your sql query like this.

```
    SELECT *
     FROM your_table
     ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1, 1;
```

**See more :** http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="Select * from table order by id desc limit 20";//It will give you last 20 records
```

Comment: It will give you the last 20 records on a mysql database, it will error on sql server.